# SFML RenderWindow Odd Characters

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm trying to get SFML to work with Visual C++ 2010, and it will open the window now, but it looks like this when it does.
[image]

The window also doesn't respond when you try and move it or close it. 
Here's my code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Headers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");

    while (true)
    {
        App.Clear();


        App.Display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to poll events every frame to let the window respond to the operating system. If you don't, you won't move or close it.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");
    while (App.IsOpened())
    {
        App.Clear();
        sf::Event event;
        while (App.PollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.Close();
        }
        App.Display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you use SFML 1.6, change `PollEvent` to `GetEvent`. Read the documentation.